# VBA Loop through files in a folder with certain filename

Tags: excel, vba

I have managed to develop this code slowly into something that is usable but isn't quite there yet. I am new to VBA and the code below so far does the following:

- Loops through workbooks in a folder
- Copies certain cells from each workbook
- Pastes those cells into rows with information organised by column
- Copies a range from each workbook
- Pastes the range (14 rows of data) beside the single rows of data formed by the single cells from each workbook (effectively creating two halves to a worksheet - one half with each single row of data belonging to a certain workbook (Columns A:E) and the other half with each range of 14 rows belonging to a certain workbook (Columns F:M))
- **All of the above is only carried out if the workbook in the folder has NOT already been looped (this is done via a function)**

  - This function looks at a column of filenames that is created by previously running the code - meaning that the filename of each looped workbook is recorded in the list created by the code and the code only copies data from workbooks with a filename that is not already included in the list.

---

**The next development of the code that I have been working on and I need help with is adding another condition - I.e making the code only look at files that have not been looped previously AND also only at files with a certain filename-ending, within the group of not looped workbooks.**

My logic in how to achieve this was to add another function just like the looped function and modify the code within it to look at the first three characters of a name that is entered in a cell and find/compare it to the not already looped filenames (the filename-ending (its **last** 3 characters) is always the **first** three characters of a name).

**This is the main code and function:**

```
Sub CopyFromFolderExample()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Dim strFolder As String, strFile As String, r As Long, wb As Workbook
Dim varTemp(1 To 5) As Variant, r1 As Long, r3 As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
strFolder = "D:\Other\folder\"
strFile = Dir(strFolder & "*.xl*")

Do While Len(strFile) > 0
    If Not Looped(strFile, ws) Then
        Application.StatusBar = "Reading data from " & strFile & "..."
        Set wb = Workbooks.Add(strFolder & strFile)
        With wb.Worksheets(1)
            varTemp(1) = strFile
            varTemp(2) = .Range("A13").Value
            varTemp(3) = .Range("H8").Value
            varTemp(4) = .Range("H9").Value
            varTemp(5) = .Range("H37").Value
            Set r3 = .Range("A20:H33")
        End With
        With ws
            r = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            r1 = .Range("F" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'last used row in col F
            .Range(.Cells(r, 1), .Cells(r, 5)).Value = varTemp
            .Cells(r1, 6).Resize(r3.Rows.Count, r3.Columns.Count).Value = r3.Value 'transfer A20:H33
        End With
        wb.Close False
    End If
  strFile = Dir
Loop

Application.StatusBar = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

---

```
Private Function Looped(strFile As String, ws As Worksheet) As Boolean

    Dim Found As Range
    Set Found = ws.Range("A:A").Find(strFile)

    If Found Is Nothing Then
        Looped = False
    Else
        Looped = True
    End If

    End Function
```

**This is the modified function that I have been trying to use by adding another `IF`statement into the code - unsuccessfully:**

```
Private Function notx(strFile As String, ws As Worksheet) As Boolean

Dim Found As Range
Set Found = strFile.Find(Left(ws.Range("P1").Value, 3))

If Found Is Nothing Then
    notx = False
Else
    notx = True
End If

End Function
```

Comment: Your `strFile` is a string and you cannot use `.Find` in a string. Try `InStr`. Basically change `Set Found = strFile.Find(Left(ws.Range("P1").Value, 3))` to someting like `Dim Found As Integer
Found = InStr(1, strFile, Left(ws.Range("P1").Value, 3))`

Comment: Thanks for your help, that makes sense, but I get a "Compile error: Type mismatch". I don't think the function is liking the fact that Found is now an Integer. Can an integer be used in this way within an if statement?

Comment: You need to change your `notx` function. `Private Function notx(strFile As String, ws As Worksheet) As Boolean

Dim Found As Integer
Found = InStr(1, strFile, Left(ws.Range("P1").Value, 3))

If Found = 0 Then
    notx = False
Else
    notx = True
End If

End Function`

Comment: Literally was just writing a thank you comment, as I got it to work in exactly the same way! Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `strFile` is a string and you cannot use `.Find` in a string. Try changing your `notx` function to something like:

```
Private Function notx(strFile As String, ws As Worksheet) As Boolean

Dim Found As Integer
Found = InStr(1, strFile, Left(ws.Range("P1").Value, 3))

If Found = 0 Then
    notx = False
Else
    notx = True
End If

End Function
```

Comment: It works exactly in the way that I wanted it to! thank you!